# Restricting Method Parameter to a Specific Type in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I have a function that I would like it to be generic but restrict it to take a certain subtypes. To keep things simple, I want my function to just work on Long, Int, Float and Double. So here is what I have come up with:

```
def covariance[A](xElems: Seq[A], yElems: Seq[A]): A = {
  val (meanX, meanY) = (mean(xElems), mean(yElems))
  val (meanDiffX, meanDiffY) = (meanDiff(meanX, xElems), meanDiff(meanY, yElems))
  ((meanDiffX zip meanDiffY).map { case (x, y) => x * y }.sum) / xElems.size - 1
}

def mean[A](elems: Seq[A]): A = {
  (elems.fold(_ + _)) / elems.length
}

def meanDiff[A](mean: A, elems: Seq[A]) = {
  elems.map(elem => elem - mean)
}
```

Here is the method that I will use to check for the above mentioned types:

```
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}
def matchList2[A : ClassTag](list: List[A]) = list match {
  case intlist: List[Int @unchecked] if classTag[A] == classTag[Int] => println("A List of ints!")
  case longlist: List[Long @unchecked] if classTag[A] == classTag[Long] => println("A list of longs!")
}
```

Notice that I'm using ClassTag. I can also use a TypeTag and perhaps even the Shapeless library.

I would like to know if this is a good approach? Or should I use bounded types to solve what I want?

EDIT: Based on the comment and suggestion to use the Fractional Typeclass, here is how I think it could work!

```
def covariance[A: Fractional](xElems: Seq[A], yElems: Seq[A]): A = {
  val (meanX, meanY) = (mean(xElems), mean(yElems))
  val (meanDiffX, meanDiffY) = (meanDiff(meanX, xElems), meanDiff(meanY, yElems))
  ((meanDiffX zip meanDiffY).map { case (x, y) => x * y }.sum) / xElems.size - 1
}

def mean[A](elems: Seq[A]): A = {
  (elems.fold(_ + _)) / elems.length
}

def meanDiff[A](mean: A, elems: Seq[A]) = {
  elems.map(elem => elem - mean)
}
```

Comment: It looks to me, that what you really need is a [**Typeclass**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html) - and, in your particular example, I believe the [`Fractional`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Fractional.html) **Typeclass** of the _standard_ library is what you need.

Comment: Could you post some examples?

Comment: Please, do not post answer in the question. Post it as an answer instead.

Comment: Why should I make it generic in the first place? I guess it would anyways be a fraction as soon as I divide. Isn't it? I guess it would be enough just to use Double as a parameter instead of the generic type!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments and inputs, here is what I came up with!

```
def mean[A](xs: Seq[A])(implicit A: Fractional[A]): A =
  A.div(xs.sum, A.fromInt(xs.size))

def covariance[A](xs: Seq[A], ys: Seq[A])(implicit A: Fractional[A]): A = {
  val (meanX, meanY) = (mean(xs), mean(ys))
  val (meanDiffX, meanDiffY) = (meanDiff(meanX, xs), meanDiff(meanY, ys))
  (meanDiffX zip meanDiffY).map { case (x, y) => A.div(A.times(x, y), A.fromInt(xs.size - 1)) }.sum
}

def meanDiff[A](mean: A, elems: Seq[A])(implicit A: Fractional[A]): Seq[A] = {
  elems.map(elem => A.minus(elem, mean))
}
```

Comment: How do I call my functions now? It fails with an implicit now found error - could not find implicit value for parameter A: Fractional[Int]

Comment: `implicit object IntIsFractional extends Fractional[Int] with Ordering.IntOrdering {
    def plus(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y
    def minus(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x - y
    def times(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x * y
    def quot(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x / y
    def rem(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x % y
    def negate(x: Int): Int = -x
    def fromInt(x: Int): Int = x
    def toInt(x: Int): Int = x
    def toLong(x: Int): Long = x.toLong
    def toFloat(x: Int): Float = x.toFloat
    def toDouble(x: Int): Double = x.toDouble
    override def div(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x / y
  }`

Comment: Define an instance for it like in `scala.math.Numeric`